# Is connectionPoolSetting for single mongos instance or the whole cluster?

Tags: java, mongodb, connection-pooling, sharding

I am a server-side developer, working on a project which uses a mongo cluster as persistent database.

I have a question for https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.8/javadoc/com/mongodb/connection/ConnectionPoolSettings.html

It said `to a MongoDB server`
But what if I have a connectionString like following one

```
mongodb://user:pwd@mongos1:port,mongos3:port,mongos3:port,mongos4:port,mongos5:port,mongos6:port/admin?readPreference=secondaryPreferred
```

A mongodb sharded cluster which has 6 mongos instance.

Question:
Is the connectionPoolSetting related to one mongos server? or related to all mongos servers?

E.g. if we have maxSize = 10 in this setting, does it mean single client has max connection pool = 10 for single mongos server (max pool = 60 for my 6 mongos cluster)? Or max connection pool = 10 for the whole cluster no matter how many mongos server we have?

Answer (score 0):

max connection pool = 10 means that in the client pool there will be max 10 connections no matter hoe many server are part of your cluster.

Answer (score 0):

**Mongo Client**

`com.mongodb.client.MongoClient` *interface*:

> A client-side representation of a MongoDB cluster. Instances can represent either a standalone MongoDB instance, a replica set, or a sharded cluster. Instance of this class are responsible for maintaining an up-to-date state of the cluster, and possibly cache resources related to this, including background threads for monitoring, and connection pools.

`MongoClient` object is used to get access to the database, using the `getDatebase()` method and work with collections and documents in it.

From the [documentation](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.12/driver/getting-started/quick-start/):

> The MongoClient instance represents a pool of connections to the
>   database; you will only need one instance of class MongoClient even
>   with multiple threads.
>
> IMPORTANT 
>   Typically you only create one MongoClient instance for a
>   given MongoDB deployment (e.g. standalone, replica set, or a sharded 
>   cluster) and use it across your application. However, if you do create
>   multiple instances:
>
> All resource usage limits (e.g. max connections, etc.) apply per
>   MongoClient instance.
>     To dispose of an instance, call MongoClient.close() to clean up resources.

The following code creates a MongoDB client connection object with connection pooling to connect to a MongoDB instance.

```
MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create();
MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("test");
```

`MongoClients.create()` static method creates a connection object specified by the default host (localhost) and port (27017). You can explicitly specify other settings with the `MongoClientSettings` which specifies various settings to control the behavior of a `MongoClient`.

```
MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(MongoClientSettings settings)
```

**Connection Pool Settings:**

The `ConnectionPoolSettings` object specifies all settings that relate to the pool of connections to a MongoDB server. The application creates this connection pool when the client object is created. This creating of connection pool is driver specific.

`ConnectionPoolSettings.Builder` is a builder for `ConnectionPoolSettings` has methods to specify the connection pool properties. E.g., `maxSize​(int maxSize)`: The maximum number of connections allowed. Default is `100`. Other methods include, `minSize`, `maxConnectionIdleTime`, etc.

Code to instantiate a `MongoClient` with connection pool settings:

```
MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
                                   .applyToConnectionPoolSettings(builder ->
                                       builder.maxSize(20).minSize(10)
                                    .build();
MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(settings);
//...
// Verify the connection pool settings max size as
settings.getConnectionPoolSettings().getMaxSize()
```

---

> Question: Is the connectionPoolSetting related to one mongos server?
>   or related to all mongos servers?

A client or application connects to the sharded cluster (includes all its shards) via the `mongos` router. The client program specifies the URL connection string and other options for the connection. In a sharded cluster, a client may connect thru a set of `mongos`s or a single `mongos`, or multiple clients can connect thru a single `mongos`, etc.,; it depends upon your application architecture.

If you are connecting via a single `mongos`, you can specify the `mongos`'s host, port, user/password, etc., in the connection string. If it is a multiple `mongos`'s, then multiple host/port values. Irrespective of the number of `mongos`'s, the client program connects to the cluster via only one `mongos`.

The connection pool setting is for one `mongos` router only, as an application connects to one `mongos` irrespective of the number of `mongos`s specified in the connection string.

Comment: Thanks for your answer~!
But when I tried to look at the socket info on one of my application server, the socket connections happen between different mongos and my app server. It doesn't sound like `an application connects to one mongos irrespective of the number of mongoss specified in the connection string.` as you said

```
ESTAB      0      0      app_ip:37588              mongos1_ip:port
ESTAB      0      0      app_ip:37589              mongos2_ip:port
ESTAB      0      0      app_ip:37590              mongos1_ip:port
```

Comment: The reason you use multiple `mongos` routers is for redundancy. When the application cannot connect via a router_1, then it will connect via router_2, etc. The connection will not fail. The point is that an application connects to the cluster via one router for each connection, and it can be any of the available routers. If you have only one `mongos` in your configuration then it always connects via that one only.